# Regex to remove white space after first word

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I thought this would be simple, but I cannot figure this out.

I am trying to remove the first whitespace chunk in a postal code.

```
ss 0 9ej = ss0 9ej
```

`\s+` removes all spaces.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A22, "^(\S*)\s+", "$1")
```

The `^(\S*)\s+` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S*)` - Group 1: zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars.

The `$1` is a placeholder that inserts the Group 1 value back into the resulting string.

[image]

Comment: you just saved me around 2-4 hours of manual work, you are the man.